# Run an application made on java(FX) on a webpage

Tags: java, javafx, browser

i am currently writing a game on javaFX and i have plans to post it in the website i run in the future (end exploit the Ads while at it). The problem is that after searching around a little it seems there is no way to run a java application on a browser.

Allowing people to run it through the browser would really help sharing the program.

My question is: is there today(2018) any way to run a java application through the web? Though i like java, no browser support seems like a really, really bad idea.

Oh, i also heard of Java Web Start. Although it looks like it is just avoiding the problem (not running in the browser) it seems like a good way to share an application. The problem is that it seems it is (Will be?) deprecated? I am helpless, it is like java isn't even trying anymore...

PS: If it makes any difference my game would be a 2D game with 3rd person view. It will also require some server stuff since players will create "arenas" that others can challenge. I would say my game wouldn't be "simple".

Comment: *"The problem is that after searching around a little it seems there is no way to run a java application on a browser."* - Yep, that's correct. *"no browser support seems like a really, really bad idea"* - Okay, go back to the 1990's when `Applet` first came out - what fun those days were, even back then, security was a nightmare, fast forward to now and, well, it's much worse and browser developers are feed up with all the plugins "leaking" so they've begun removing support for plugins - so even if a "plugin" existed to do what you wanted, it wouldn't run in most browsers

Comment: A bunch of web developers will also tell that they could make your game using CSS, Javascript and HTML 5- I say, good luck to them personally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java Web Start does the job very well—if you are willing to pay for a code signing certificate.  (They’re a lot more expensive than regular SSL certificates.)  The idea is that a user clicks on a hyperlink on your page, which causes the user’s Java installation to launch your application (possibly after installing it).  This requires users to have Java installed beforehand.

If you don’t have the resources or desire to go with a code signing certificate, you can look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/self-contained-application-packaging.htm.  It allows you to create native installation packages for JavaFX applications.  The disadvantage:  You need each platform to create an installer for it.  Meaning, you need Windows to create a Windows installer, OS X to create an OS X installation image, and Linux to create a Linux package.  Some may also require signing using native tools.

Java 9 includes the [jmod](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jmod.htm) and [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm) tools, which are capable of creating a file tree with an executable shell script or .bat file.  A major advantage is that you can build such a tree for any platform, regardless of your own platform, if you unpackage the foreign platform’s JDK on your machine.  Another advantage is that the user doesn’t need to have Java installed at all.  A disadvantage is that the script requires a terminal, unless running on Linux.

Of course, you can just go the manual route and distribute a zip file which contains your .jar file(s), a shell script you’ve written, and a .bat file you’ve written.  It’s not elegant, but it’s better than nothing.  But it may trip up some non-technical users.

There exist a number of tools which create a native executable from .jar files, but I am not familiar with them (and I prefer to avoid third party tools unless they are truly necessary).

Whatever approach you choose, the answer is the same:  You distribute something on your web page which the user downloads and runs.  Aside from the download process, the browser is not involved.

What you can’t do is have users run your application *inside* the browser.  That is [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html), with good reason:  It’s a disaster for the browser performance, for the Java runtime, for security, and for the user experience.  And Firefox has all but banned plugins, so you’d be locking out a substantial percentage of users.